# How to auto-fill a form after doing a search

Tags: php, html

For a games reservation system that I have created, I have made a search bar to allow for easier navigation of the games available. However, to make the system quicker to make a reservation, I would like to create a link to a form that would automatically post the details of the game into the reservation form, but I'm not sure how.

Here is the code I used to create the search bar, if needed.

```
$sql= "select * from games ";

if (isset($_POST['search_box'])) {
    $search= mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['search_box']); 

    $sql .= "WHERE GameName LIKE '%{$search}%' "; 
    $sql .= " OR GameDescription LIKE '%{$search}%'";
    $sql .= " OR GameID LIKE '%{$search}%'";

}

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

After the PHP code, I used HTML, to create a search form:

```
<form name="search_form" method="POST" action="index.php">

Search: <input type="text" name="search_box" value="">
<input type="submit" name = "search" value = "Search">
</form>
```

Comment: Do not use `mysql_` functions, they are deprecated and marked to be removed next PHP version. Consider switching to `mysqli_` or `PDO`. This way you can skip, also, the use of `mysql_real_escape_string` and build a statement with bound parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass the parameters in the url. For example, build a link like so:
    `<a href="/link-to-reservation-form?game=Zelda&sky=blue">Link to reservation form</a>`

Then on your reservation form page, use php to check the query string for those parameters using `$_GET['game']` (would return "Zelda") and `$_GET['sky']` (would return "blue").

Comment: Also, make sure you do some sanitizing of the passed values, so people can't inject malicious code in your URL